# Rails 5, Ckeditor, Cloudinary: Cannot upload local images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, cloudinary

Having a headache after weeks of research..

I'm using rails 5.2 and trying to get CKEditor4 to work with Carrierwave and Cloudinary for a blog. Everything is working fine, except uploading **local** images.

### [when I hit send it to server or browse server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpqWO.png)

Even though I'm getting 500 error each time, each image is getting saved in public/uploads/ckeditor/..

Heroku logs errors:

- Completed 500 Internal Server Error
- ArgumentError (Version content doesn't exist!):
- app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:6:in `url'
- app/models/ckeditor/picture.rb:10:in `url_content'

My ckeditor.rb:

```html
# Use this hook to configure ckeditor
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default), :mongo_mapper and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'ckeditor/orm/active_record'
  config.cdn_url = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/full/ckeditor.js"
  # config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'http://dashboard/vendors/editor/uploader/upload.php?CKEditorFuncNum=1'

  # Allowed image file types for upload.
  # Set to nil or [] (empty array) for all file types
  # By default: %w(jpg jpeg png gif tiff)
  config.image_file_types = %w(jpg jpeg png gif tiff)

  # Allowed flash file types for upload.
  # Set to nil or [] (empty array) for all file types
  # By default: %w(jpg jpeg png gif tiff)
  config.flash_file_types = %w(swf)

  # Allowed attachment file types for upload.
  # Set to nil or [] (empty array) for all file types
  # By default: %w(doc docx xls odt ods pdf rar zip tar tar.gz swf)
  config.attachment_file_types = %w(doc docx xls odt ods pdf rar zip tar tar.gz swf)

  # Setup authorization to be run as a before filter
  # By default: there is no authorization.
  # config.authorize_with :cancancan

  # Override parent controller CKEditor inherits from
  # By default: 'ApplicationController'
  # config.parent_controller = 'MyController'

  # Asset model classes
  # config.picture_model { Ckeditor::Picture }
  # config.attachment_file_model { Ckeditor::AttachmentFile }

  # Paginate assets
  # By default: 24
  # config.default_per_page = 24

  # Customize ckeditor assets path
  # By default: nil
  # config.asset_path = 'http://www.example.com/assets/ckeditor/'

  # CKEditor CDN
  # More info here http://cdn.ckeditor.com/
  # By default: nil (CDN disabled)
  # config.cdn_url = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.3/standard/ckeditor.js'

  # JS config url
  # Used when CKEditor CDN enabled
  # By default: "ckeditor/config.js"
  config.js_config_url = 'ckeditor/config.js'
end
```

photo_uploader.rb:

```html
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick


  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  process eager: true  # Force version generation at upload time.

  process convert: 'jpg'

  version :thumnail do
    resize_to_fit 256, 256
  end

  # version :bright_face do
  #   cloudinary_transformation effect: "brightness:30", radius: 20,
  #     width: 150, height: 150, crop: :thumb, gravity: :face
  # end
  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_whitelist
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
  def public_id
    name = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    return name+"_"+Rails.env
  end
end
```

ckeditor_picture_uploader.rb:

```html
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick


  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience
  process eager: true  # Force version generation at upload time.

  process convert: 'jpg'

  version :thumnail do
    resize_to_fit 256, 256
  end
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/ckeditor/pictures/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
    # version :thumb do
    #   process resize_to_fill: [118, 100]
    # end

    # version :content do
    #   process resize_to_limit: [800, 800]
    # end
  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   Ckeditor.image_file_types
  # end
end
```

models/ckeditor/picture.rb:

```html
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  mount_uploader :data, CkeditorPictureUploader, mount_on: :data_file_name
def self.inheritance_column
  nil
end

  def url_content
    url(:content) || begin
      if persisted?
        reload
        url(:content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems to complain about the `content` version and I see it's commented out in your snippet. When you are restarting your server are you restarting the rails console? In addition, you may want to replace include CarrierWave::MiniMagick with CarrierWave::RMagick.

Comment: @AleksandarKostadinov my bad. Okay I uncommented content version, same for thumb version. And now it's raising an error 
"ActionView::Template::Error (Version thumb doesn't exist!)"
     7:           class: "fileupload-cancel gal-del" %>
     8: 
     9:   <div class="fileupload-file gal-inner-holder">
    10:     <div class="img"><%= image_tag(asset.url_thumb, title: asset.filename) %></div>
    11:     <div class="img-data">
    12:       <div class="img-name"><%= asset.filename %></div>
    13:       <div class="time-size">
app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:6:in `url'

Comment: @AleksandarKostadinov app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb:6:in `url':      
3 class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base . 
4 include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase . 
5 . 
6 delegate :url, :current_path, :content_type, to: :data . 
7 . 
8 validates :data, presence: true . 9 end